# Entity Framework - TPH Query Issue

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have  model that looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Parent {}

public class Child1 : Parent {}

public class Child2 : Parent {}

public class SomeEntity 
{
    public virtual Parent SomeParent { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to query the SomeEntity class and filter by the ones where SomeParent is a Child1.  I tried to write the following Linq query:

```
dbContext.Set<SomeEntity>().Where(s => s.SomeParent is Child1)
```

When i run this query, I get the following error:

error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 64:Condition member 'Parent.DiscriminatorColumn' with a condition other than 'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on Parent.DiscriminatorColumn or remove it from the mapping.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this supposed to work?

Comment: Deleted my answer. I missed the code-first tag, partly because I was not paying attention and partly because I've only got this exception in database-first contexts. With code-first the discriminator column can also be addresses as a property. I tried your model, didn't get the exception. Maybe you abstracted it out for the simplicity of the question. Can you think of more details that might be relevant?

Comment: It actually was because the discriminator columns was mapped. It wasn't in my EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent> class, but the property existed in my Parent model so it was being automatically mapped.